# How to dynamic assign type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I met a wrapper function type problem.

I want turn a function with callbacks into a promise function. almost of those functions are like this:

```js
func({
  success:....,
  fail:....,
  complete:...
})
```

and I wrote a wrapper function:

```js
function toAsync<
        OptType
        SuccesResType,
        FailResType>(fn:(opt:OptType)=>any):(opt:OptType)=>Promise<SuccesResType>{
  
  return async (opt:OptType):Promise<SuccesResType>=>{
    return new Promise<SuccesResType>((resolve,reject)=>{
      fn({
        ...(opt || {}),
        success(res:SuccesResType){
          resolve(res)
        },
        fail(res:FailResType){
          reject(res)
        }
      } as unknown as OptType)
    })
  }
}
```

and there is the problem, basically the `SuccessResType` is parameter type of `opt.success`,
`FailResType` is the parameter type of `opt.fail`.

how can I define my `toAsync` wrapper to function to get the right type hint when use it like this:

```js
const fn = toAsync(fn)
```

instead of some duplicated works like

```js
type fnOptType = Parameters<typeof fn>[0]
type fnSuccessRestype = Parameters<fnOptType.SuccessCallback>[0]
type fnFailResType = Parameters<fnOptType.FailCallback>[0]
type fn = toAsync<fnOptType,fnSuccessRestype,fnFailResType>(fn)
```

Right now, if I use `toAsync` like `const fn = toAsync(fn)`, I can't get any hint option until I manually write the generic type.

Update:
for `fn`, its option type can change.like:

```js
function request(opt:{
    fail?:(res:RequestFailResType)=>any;
    success?:(res:RequestSuccessResType)=>any;
    complete?:(res:RequestCompleteResType)=>any;
    url:string
}):any{
    // do things here
}

function locationQuery(opt:{
    fail?:(res:QueryFailResType)=>any;
    success?:(res:QuerySuccessResType)=>any;
    complete?:(res:QueryCompleteResType)=>any;
    lat:number,
    log:number
}):any{
    // do things here
}
```

`toAsync` needs to handle those type changes. It seems a big compatible requirement.

I have hundreds of functions like this, therefore I want a more convenient way to do this backwards type support.

Comment: Are these functions declared externally? Do you have control to change types of these functions a little?

Comment: basically no. I can't change those function types. Because they belongs to a third party library. If I manually handle the type changes, when others upgrade the lib, it might not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make `OptType` generic. Like this-

```
interface OptType <T1, T2> {
  complete: () => void
  success: (successResult: T1) => void
  fail: (failResult: T2) => void
}
```

Then you can pass the argument to `toAsync` with generics involved-

```
fn: (opt: OptType<SuccessResType, FailResType>) => any
```

This time the types for `SuccessResType` and `FailResType` will be inferred automatically. The whole solution will be-

```
declare function myFunc(opts: MyFuncOptType): void

interface OptType <T1, T2, T3> {
  complete?: (res: T3) => void
  success?: (successResult: T1) => void
  fail?: (failResult: T2) => void
}

type SuccessResultType<O extends OptType<any, any, any>> = O extends OptType<infer T1, any, any>
  ? T1
  : never

type FailResultType<O extends OptType<any, any, any>> = O extends OptType<any, infer T2, any>
  ? T2
  : never

declare interface MyFuncOptType extends OptType<number, boolean, any> {
  someProp: string
  someOtherProp: boolean[]
  someFunc: (p: number) => string
}

function toAsync<O extends OptType<any, any, any>>(fn: (opt: O) => any) {
  return async (opt: Omit<O, 'success' | 'fail' | 'complete'>) => {
    return new Promise<SuccessResultType<O>>((resolve, reject) => {
      fn({
        ...(opt || {}),
        success(res: SuccessResultType<O>){
          resolve(res)
        },
        fail(res: FailResultType<O>){
          reject(res)
        }
      } as unknown as O)
    })
  }
}

const promisedMyFunc = toAsync(myFunc)
promisedMyFunc({
  someProp: 'va',
  someOtherProp: [false],
  someFunc: (p) => p.toString()
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res) // res is number
})

function request(opt:{
    fail?: (res: string) => any;
    success?: (res: boolean) => any;
    complete?: () => any;
    url: string
}): any{
    // do things here
}

const promisedRequest = toAsync(request)
promisedRequest({
  url: '',
}).then((res) => { // res is Blob
  console.log(res)
})

function locationQuery(opt:{
    fail?:(res: 'type1') => any;
    success?:(res: 'type2') => any;
    complete?:(res: 'type3') => any;
    lat:number,
    log:number
}): any {
    // do things here
}


const promisedLocationQuery = toAsync(locationQuery)
promisedLocationQuery({
  lat: 34,
  log: 34
}).then((res) => { // res is "type2"
  console.log(res)
})
```

[[Playground]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsBPAMTTAAocAHDAZwC54BZU8geVoBUjqQBKJgDccWYAChxWVBhAxEUMAk4YefeAB4uARgA08LgCZ9XAMwA+eAG9x8eGBwFqEELID8TCnEYHT-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-BnueGbrhAryfvwL5Hk0z7AUU3wQJ+TBfD8C5-kMvZAcBO57hBUEDi0wFNOs0xoAA1qgOCjrmhyQdBdHwC0roOKgsrwNQUpTiAwA0uQgTen6+aUMQFqQRxjhYNOPFsOgp6mhKUrWk2QhQJWsHhCq6qaopTAGgoEDTka6mimaFpWg61AXj6HROqgCoUJBj5WRqJ4QYElj9ixoouBeEA4PZ3j+AA9EFg7JCi0xspybyPpI7qYLg+BwAAjsgyQYDeWRARUZTeDKtkKimSwANwvm+MS5ckTC6gKqBFUQpVHh2ziuCAZT1Y1A7ZhA+XynZLqCFGQEhfAwA4N6aqKtMGpwC6kheRg7GcZJ3FpKl6X8T6-qBpQKVpbKYnLVJa37Rl-bdUwlZqQNzn7KugXudY8Ajd4EXwAAQn5HJhF5eq+f5eGxW65CevgflgFAoMAIppTARCZQw2UIR4SFNm0fDaJWHVld074o3laPtIYWOPasnV2M1XZtQwqOVujICmCTeRky+0BZFFdrqXYfkKgwHMxYNqzCkeI1jRNU3wDNIBzfNeBseJXHAAAMjgEPQ7DRCbYJO0UODkOJTDchEIdElSSrasGxrcnc5DTCmAALOpPN2-bN1aa5D15FYz2ha9knwAARPThgBz9ct-TzgOQeIQA)

Please note that I have removed unnecessary types. And rename `T1` and `T2` to your convenience.

Comment: thanks bro. I tried your solution. but I met another problem. `OptType` is just a basic type, which won't contain all fields in `fn` option, for example, there is a function `request` and field `url` in request option is required, if I use `toAsync(request)`, the compatible error will show who says that `url` in `request option` is required. How can I solve compatible problem like this?

Comment: @ucag Could you please add an such example in the question?

Comment: OK, please wait for minutes.

Comment: updated an example. please have a look.

Comment: @ucag I had updated the solution

Comment: OHHHHHHH, It works! YOU ARE A GENIUS! Love you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!